# Find a way to retrive data updated through metabox plugin to web page

Tags: php, custom-field, metabox, meta-value

I developed a customer metabox plugin to save user details to db and retrieve them back to Contact Us Page in my website.

But I searched a way to retrieve the data to contact us page and I couldn't find a way.

Please look into this code and kindly tell me a way to retrieve the data updated through `metabox.php` to `page-contact.php`

**metabox.php**

```
<?php

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'wpl_owt_register_metabox_cpt');
function wpl_owt_register_metabox_cpt()
{
    global $post;

    if(!empty($post))
    {
        $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

        if($pageTemplate == 'page-contact.php' )
        {
            add_meta_box(
                'owt-cpt-id', // $id
                'Contact Details', // $title
                'wpl_owt_book_function', // $callback
                'page', // $page
                'normal', // $context
                'high'); // $priority
        }
    }
}


   /**********Callback function for metabox at custom post type book******************/

 function wpl_owt_book_function( $post ) {
    //echo "<p>Custom metabox for custom post type</p>";

    define("_FILE_", "_FILE_");

    wp_nonce_field( basename(_FILE_), "wp_owt_cpt_nonce");

    echo "<label for='txtPhoneNum'>Phone</label><br>";
    $phone_num = get_post_meta($post->ID, "telNo" , true);
    echo "<input type ='tel' name = 'txtPhoneNum' value = '" . $phone_num . "'' placeholder = 'Phone Number' /><br><br>";

    echo "<label for='txtEmail'>Email</label><br>";
    $email = get_post_meta($post->ID, "email" , true);
    echo "<input type ='email' name = 'txtEmail' value = '" . $email . "'' placeholder = 'Email Address' /><br><br>";

    echo "<label for='txtHours'>Hours of Operation</label><br>";
    $hours = get_post_meta($post->ID, "hourofOps" , true);
    echo "<input type ='text' name = 'txtHours' value = '" . $hours . "'' placeholder = 'Working Hours' /><br><br>";
}

add_action("save_post" , "wpl_owt_save_metabox_data" , 10 , 2);

function wpl_owt_save_metabox_data($post_id, $post){

    //verify nonce
    if(!isset($_POST['wp_owt_cpt_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wp_owt_cpt_nonce'], basename(_FILE_))){
        return $post_id;
    }

    //verify slug value
    $post_slug = "page";
    if($post_slug != $post->post_type){
        return;
    }

    //save value to db filed
    $pub_tel = '';
    if(isset($_POST['txtPhoneNum'])){
        $pub_tel = sanitize_text_field($_POST['txtPhoneNum']);
    }

    else{
        $pub_tel = '';
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, "telNo", $pub_tel);


    $pub_email = '';

    if(isset($_POST['txtEmail'])){
        $pub_email = sanitize_text_field($_POST['txtEmail']);
    }

    else{
        $pub_email = '';
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, "email", $pub_email);


    $pub_hours = '';

    if(isset($_POST['txtHours'])){
        $pub_hours = sanitize_text_field($_POST['txtHours']);
    }
    update_post_meta($post_id, "hourofOps", $pub_hours);
}

?>
```

**page-contact.php**

```
 <!-- Contact Info -->
 <div class="contact-info col-md-4 col-sm-4 margin-top-20 padding-left-20">
    <label class="contact-label pull-left width-wide">Contact Info</label>
    <p><strong>IT'S SHOWTIME TOWING</strong><br /><br /> Phone: <a href="tel:0450749863">0450749863</a><br /><br /> 
    Email: <a href="mailto:info@itsshowtimetowing.com.au">info@itsshowtimetowing.com.au</a><br /><br /> 
   <strong>Hours of Operation</strong><br /><br /> 
   <a href="#">24/7</a><br /><br /> <strong>Terms And Conditions</strong> <a href="terms_conditions.html">Click Here</a></p>                    
</div>
<!-- // Contact Info -->
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

So finally I found a way to do that.

Here is the code.

**page-contact.php**

```
 <!-- Contact Info -->
                    <div class="contact-info col-md-4 col-sm-4 margin-top-20 padding-left-20">
                        <label class="contact-label pull-left width-wide">Contact Info</label>

                         <p><strong>IT'S SHOWTIME TOWING</strong><br /><br /> 
                            <!--Phone: <a href="tel:0450749863">0450749863</a><br /><br /> -->
                            Phone: <a href="tel:0450749863"><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'telNo', true );?></a><br /><br />
                            <!--Email: <a href="mailto:info@itsshowtimetowing.com.au">info@itsshowtimetowing.com.au</a><br /><br /> -->
                            Email: <a href="mailto:info@itsshowtimetowing.com.au"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "email" , true); ?></a><br /><br />
                            <strong>Hours of Operation</strong><br /><br /> 
                            <!--<a href="#">24/7</a><br /><br />-->
                            <a href="#"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "hourofOps" , true); ?></a><br /><br /> 
                            <strong>Terms And Conditions</strong> <a href="terms_conditions.html">Click Here</a>
                         </p>                    
                         </div><!-- // Contact Info -->
```

Hope this answer will helpful for a newcomer to the industry like me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to also fetch the value in `href` attribute as wel. Currently there are  static value you have added. when you change value from backend it just display but when you click it will consider `tel:` and `mail:`  attribute value. So change code as below:

```
Phone: <a href="tel:<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'telNo', true );?>"><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'telNo', true );?></a><br /><br />


Email: <a href="mailto:<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'email' , true); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'email' , true); ?></a><br /><br />
```

Comment: Thanks mate for your addition!